# problem getting the token from my link to my token authentication function, what am i missing?

Tags: python, flask, token

I'm trying to have a **FORGOT PASSWORD?** functionality in my website, I'm simply generating a token with a user id and then I send the form where they can update their password along with this token, but the problem is that I can't actually get that token after I click on the link, I get none, can someone tell me what I'm missing exactly? here's what I've done so far:

```
# generates the token with the user id
def get_reset_password_token(user_id, expires_in=1800):
    return jwt.encode({'reset_password': user_id, 'exp': time() + expires_in},
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')

# verfies the token recovered from the link
def verify_reset_password_token(token):
    try:
        id = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithms=['HS256'])['reset_password']
    except:
        print("token was invalid.")
        return None
    return print("all good")

# sends email to the user containing reset password link
def send_password_reset_email(user_id, user_mail):
    token = get_reset_password_token(user_id)
    msg = Message('[El-menu] Password Reset Request', sender ='noreply@demo.com', recipients =[user_mail])
    msg.body = f'''To reset your password, visit the following link:

{url_for('reset_password', token=token , _external=True)}

If you didn't make this request, ignore this email and no changes will be madeSincerely,

Sincerely,

El-menu Team
'''
    mail.send(msg)

    return  print("email sent with token " + token +" to email " + user_mail, file=sys.stderr)


@app.route("/reset_password_request", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def reset_password_request():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form.get("email")

        # checks for valid mail
        if not email:
            error = "you must submit a valid email"
            return render_template("reset_password_request.html", error = error)
        # performs a query to find information about given email, whether it's in the system or not?
        user = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= :email", email = email)


        if user:
            user_mail = user[0]['email']
            user_id = user[0]['id']
            send_password_reset_email(user_id, user_mail)
        password_reset = "Password reset link has been sent to your email!"
        return render_template("login.html", password_reset = password_reset)

    else:
        return render_template("reset_password_request.html")

@app.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def reset_password(token):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("trying to reset password now..", file=sys.stderr)
        print(token, file=sys.stderr)
        user_id = verify_reset_password_token(token)
        print(user_id, file=sys.stderr)
        if not user_id:
            print("token is none", file=sys.stderr)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        print(user_id, file=sys.stderr)
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")
        # Ensure password was submitted
        if not password:
            error = "You must provide a password"
            return render_template("reset_password.html", error = error)

        # Ensure confirmation was submitted
        elif not confirmation:
            error = "You must provide a password confirmation"
            return render_template("reset_password.html", error = error)

        reg = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d@$!#%*?&]{8,}$"

        # compiling regex
        pat = re.compile(reg)

        # searching regex
        mat = re.search(pat, password)

        # validating conditions
        if not mat:
            error = "Password is weak"
            return render_template("reset_password.html", error = error)

        # Ensure Passwords match
        if password != confirmation:
            error = "Password and confirmation must match!"
            return render_template("reset_password.html", error = error)

        # Hash password
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET hash = :hash WHERE id = :id", hash = hashed_password, id = user_id)

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("reset_password.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's because the link you give `{url_for('reset_password', token=token , _external=True)}` in `send_password_request_email` makes a GET request so the user gets in `reset_password` and directly gets returned `return render_template("reset_password.html")`

Comment: tbh, that doesn't make sense to me because when I click the link and get redirected back to my website, I could see the token in the URL, so I thought it should get that token, but  you're actually right  because when I deleted the POST if statements, it worked perfectly, I got the token and i decoded it, but now with POST if statement gone, how am i to submit the new password and confirmation?

Comment: never mind, I managed to solve it, thank you for pointing this out to me tho :)!

Comment: You need to add a form with POST method in your template, but I guess that's what you did!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `render_template` in order to render an email body that understands what `token` is.

So the first step would be to create an email template for the body of the email. The next step would be to use `render_template` and pass the token in.

Example from one of my Flask apps:

```py
message = Message(
    subject=render_template("email/reset_subject.txt"),
    recipients=[user.email]
)

salt = current_app.config.get("SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT", b"")

message.html = render_template(
    "email/reset.html",
    token=generate_code(user.email, salt=salt)
)
mail.send(message)
```

Comment: I'm sure that's not the problem, my approach to send the user an email with the link to the form and a token attached to it works perfectly and to be extra sure, I've used a couple of print() to make sure of the output, but I like yours and I've used it just to be sure, yeah it still sends the email perfectly, but I'm not able to get the token from the link once I submit the form, that's the problem but I'm really out of ideas on how to solve it.